# jQuery Validator custom rule for min max or zero value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validator and everything works fine. But now I have a requirement of using min and max value. But here is a problem.

**Requirement**

The user can input values from `60`-`600` or `0`.

**Code**

```
<input type="number" value="0" max="600" min="60" class="form-control" id="interval" placeholder="Enter interval in seconds 0 or min. 60 - max 600" name="interval">
```

**Problem**

The issue in this is user can't input `0` value.

Comment: Read the documentation for the plugin.  You can write a custom method integrating the two requirements together.

Answer (score -1):

Try this https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/vaMgEQ

```js
$(interval).on('input propertychange', () => {
  const val = +$(interval).val()
  
  if (val === 59)
    $(interval).val(0)
  else if (val < 59 && val !== 0)
    $(interval).val(60)
  else if (val - 1 === 0)
    $(interval).val(60)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="0" max="600" class="form-control" id="interval" placeholder="Enter interval in seconds 0 or min. 60 - max 600" name="interval" id="interval">
```

Comment: yes this is my second option/ But i want to know is there any way to do this with jQuery validator library ?

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with this plugin, hope you find right solution